# How to show data in tabular format in asp.net mvc & perform edit operation without providing edit button in each row?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi I want to show data in tabular format in asp.net mvc and want to do edit,update and delete operation.In my project requirement is that we should not provide edit and delete button in each row and we should be able to do edit operation whenever we click on any data shown in tabular format & should save changes whenever we press enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for an "inline edit" then I believe.

You are probably going to need some Javascript to get a nice effect for this.

I like JQuery, so I'd use JEditable.

I'd suggest you have a read of this article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/265211/Using-JEditable-plugin-as-ASP-NET-MVC3-jQuery-inli

Scroll to the section called "Integration with DataTables"

Comment: Thanks JEditable is there but over internet we have very less articles related to asp.net mvc & JEditable So if any other is there plaese tell ?